# Is there any difference between research level 3 and max level in New Pokémon Snap?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

I maxed out the research level of the first stage, but I didn't notice any difference. Does anything change?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123806/discussion-on-question-by-blueraja-danny-pflughoeft-is-there-any-difference-be).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Maxing out research doesn't result in any course changes.** Similar to you I haven't noticed any changes on the few courses I've maxed out, but the way you can confirm this is by manually selecting your research level.

For **Park (Day)**, I've maxed out research. If I manually select the research level by pressing **X**, I see a menu showing research levels 1 through 3:

[image: park_day_research3]

Of course it's entirely possible the research menu only shows levels below your max, so I decided to rule this out by viewing the research menu for a course I haven't maxed out yet. For this test I chose the **Illumina Spot** on **Belusylva**, on which I've only unlocked research level 2. If I open the research menu here, I only see two research levels:

[image: elsewhereforest_research2]

The combination of all of the above is fairly strong confirmation that "MAX Lv." doesn't actually change anything in the course itself.

Comment: Does the professor comment about finding something new when you hit max level?

Comment: @Stevoisiak No.  I THINK he says something akin to "wow! You must know the area  even better than I do!" I could be mixing up when he says that though. I definitely don't recall him ever making a comment about something changing once you've maxed out research, and I've maxed out 4 courses so far.

Comment: Maxing out the research level is likely only relevant for the associated titles you get for reaching the max research level in 1/6/12/etc. courses.